# Convert plain text email to clickable link - REGEX/jQuery

Tags: regex, hyperlink

I am trying to convert plain text email addresses into clickable mailto links inside of a table.

I have the following function that is converting found links into mailto links, but it only seems to work for the first found link. Any subsequent links (2nd, 3rd occurrence etc.) remain as plain text links. I can't seem to figure out what I might be doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

The code:

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   <div class='filter-email-box'>
   <div>This is a sample text which contains john@gmail.com </div>
   <div>This text contains two emails adam@example.com and paul@example.com </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".filter-email-box div").filter(function(){
   var html = $(this).html();
   var emailPattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/;  

   var matched_str = $(this).html().match(emailPattern);
   if(matched_str){
       $(this).html(html.replace(emailPattern,"<a href='mailto:"+matched_str+"'>"+matched_str+"</a>"));
       return $(this)
   }    
})
```

Heres the **fiddle** I've setup:
http://jsfiddle.net/z6LF5/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When there's more than one email address, JQuery method `match` returns an array (when the *global search* flag `g` is set), so we're looping over that array (called `matched_str` in this case) and replacing the matching emails.

```
$(".filter-email-box div").filter(function () {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var emailPattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/g;  

    var matched_str = $(this).html().match(emailPattern);
    if ( matched_str ) {
      var text = $(this).html();
      $.each(matched_str, function (index, value) {
          text = text.replace(value,"<a href='mailto:"+value+"'>"+value+"</a>");
      });
      $(this).html(text);
      return $(this)
    }    
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bH9Cv/)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `g` (global) modifier which ( *finds all matches rather than stopping after the first match* ).

You could implement the following:

```
$('.filter-email-box div').ready(function() {
  $('.filter-email-box div').each(function() {
     var html  = $(this).html();
     var regex = /([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})/ig
     var text  = html.replace(regex, "<a href='mailto:$1'>$1</a>");
     $(this).html(text);
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z6LF5/24/)

Comment: exactly what I was missing in my regex. Thanks for taking the time to share the solution! I've voted this up as its directly related to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is interested I translated the jquery code to vanilla JS code

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.filter-email-box');
var html = elem.innerHTML;
if (html) {
  var regex = /([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})/ig;
  elem.innerHTML = html.replace(regex, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');
}
```

Demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/q0x4tjr3/